# How has the new review view improved our editing?

Tags: discussion, editing

The SO blog mentions the new review interface for people who are keen to improve questions. It's pretty awesome, it's automating things I've been doing by hand, so kudos there.

- [Review early, review often](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/11/review-early-review-often/)

On Meta SO they have a [neat chart](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112600/has-the-new-reviewing-interface-and-or-the-badge-objectively-reduced-spam-and-no/112692#112692) that shows progress. How are we doing in this area? It "feels" like I am seeing more posts that need to be fixed up, but this is anecdotal.

Answer (score 2):

The review view is great for finding stuff that has to be fixed up. What I get stuck on is how to fix some things up so they actually disappear from the review view!

Some one liner answers kind of answer the question, or offer something useful, but I can't think of non-invasive ways to improve them so they drop out of review, which I guess is what we're trying to achieve?

For example.. 
[How can I disable the prefetch cache?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21082/how-can-i-disable-the-prefetch-cache/82375#82375)

Sorry, this isn't really an "answer", but it wasn't a "question" either, I guess I'm just soliciting for opinions :)

Comment: You still need to click "Review question" even if the question doesn't need to be expanded to get it off the list.